# User Agent missing in an access.log of the Traefik

Tags: user-agent, traefik, access-log

I have configured Traefik 2.3.1 to write an accesslog to a file. But the log is missing User Agent (browser, OS info).

Is it somehow configurable?

The Traefik is running from docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:2.3.1 
    command:
      - "--providers.docker=true"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml:ro
      - ./logs/traefik:/logs/traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80" 
      - "443:443"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Some lines from the traefik.toml:

```
[accessLog]
  filePath = "/logs/traefik/access.log"
  bufferingSize = 100
```

And the log looks like this:

```
3.22.235.211 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:42:41 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "-" 367 "site@docker" "http://172.18.0.4:8000" 1ms
3.22.235.211 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:42:42 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 559 "-" "-" 368 "site@docker" "http://172.18.0.4:8000" 0ms
66.249.66.153 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:45:43 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 13 "-" "-" 369 "site@docker" "http://172.18.0.4:8000" 1ms
66.249.66.153 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:45:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11698 "-" "-" 370 "site@docker" "http://172.18.0.4:8000" 0ms
```

The log of nginx running behind the Traefik:

```
172.18.0.2 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:42:41 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "3.22.235.211"
172.18.0.2 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:42:42 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "3.22.235.211"
172.18.0.2 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:45:43 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 13 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "66.249.66.153"
172.18.0.2 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:45:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11698 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.113 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "66.249.66.153"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

By default traefik does not log headers in its access logs. You have to add them. Look at [this part](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/observability/access-logs/#limiting-the-fieldsincluding-headers) of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, updated *traefik.toml* and it solved the issue:

Answer (score 4):

I changed *traefik.toml* as tetram pointed and it started to work:

```
[accessLog]
  filePath = "/logs/traefik/access.log"
  bufferingSize = 100  
  [accessLog.fields.headers.names]
    "User-Agent" = "keep"
```